# Docker - cannot connect to posgres from pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I ran a docker-compose to run Postgres and pgadmin, with the following docker-compose file.
I can login to pgadmin but pgadmin cannot connect to the Postgres. However, Postgres is running smoothly and accepting requests.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@hotmail.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
```

This is the error while connecting the Postgres from pgadmin view page.

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running
> on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on
> port 5432? could not connect to server: Address not available Is the
> server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP
> connections on port 5432?

or

[image]

This is the docker-compose log.

```
db_1            | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1            | 
db_1            | 2021-02-02 04:57:59.825 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.5 (Debian 12.5-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1            | 2021-02-02 04:57:59.825 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1            | 2021-02-02 04:57:59.825 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1            | 2021-02-02 04:57:59.842 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1            | 2021-02-02 04:57:59.867 UTC [76] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-02-02 04:57:59 UTC
db_1            | 2021-02-02 04:57:59.877 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
pgadmin_1       | NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.
pgadmin_1       | 
pgadmin_1       | [2021-02-02 04:58:10 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
pgadmin_1       | [2021-02-02 04:58:10 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:5050 (1)
pgadmin_1       | [2021-02-02 04:58:10 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: threads
pgadmin_1       | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/os.py:1023: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
pgadmin_1       |   return io.open(fd, *args, **kwargs)
pgadmin_1       | [2021-02-02 04:58:10 +0000] [87] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 87
pgadmin_1       | ::ffff:192.168.80.1 - - [02/Feb/2021:05:34:52 +0000] "GET /browser/ HTTP/1.1" 302 257 "http://localhost:5050/login?next=%2Fbrowser%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1       | ::ffff:192.168.80.1 - - [02/Feb/2021:05:34:52 +0000] "GET /login?next=%2Fbrowser%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 1707 "http://localhost:5050/login?next=%2Fbrowser%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1       | 2021-02-02 05:34:52,568: ERROR    flask.app:  404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
pgadmin_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
pgadmin_1       |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1791, in dispatch_request
pgadmin_1       |     self.raise_routing_exception(req)
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1774, in raise_routing_exception
pgadmin_1       |     raise request.routing_exception
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 336, in match_request
pgadmin_1       |     self.url_adapter.match(return_rule=True)
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1945, in match
pgadmin_1       |     raise NotFound()
pgadmin_1       | werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

I don't know what could have been gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When inside the cluster, your containers intercommunicate using service name. In your case your service name is `postgres`.

The error is saying that you're trying to set server name as `localhost`. You need to set up the following settings:

[image]

Comment: No Mate, That wouldn't work.
`Unable to connect to server:`
`could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Try again`

Comment: That's strange because I just took your yaml and started it successfully

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a network and putting both containers on it:

```
version: "3"

networks:
  bridge_net:
    driver: bridge

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - bridge_net

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@hotmail.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - bridge_net

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Still the exactly the same problem, after using the network.
Earlier I created a network from docker, and ran pgadmin and postgres with docker without docker-compose, yet had the same issue.

Comment: @JageshMaharjan When you add a network you need to address the database as `postgres` from PGAdmin instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Yea, the default database based on Postgres docker-hub, is `postgres` and i named `postgres` for a database. 
i tried in small aws instance it worked. but in my local machine, it's not working.

Comment: This is Inside the posgres container,

`$ docker exec -it 062000290d78 bash` 
`root@062000290d78:/# su - postgres` 
`postgres@062000290d78:~$ psql` 

`postgres=# \t` 
`Tuples only is on.` 
`postgres=# `

Comment: Compose creates a `default` network for you, identical to the `bridge_net` you propose here but with a different name.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has more details.

Comment: I understand that, docker-compose creates a docker default network. As well we can create manually. But either doesn't solve the above problem.